# Single colon in XPath selector meaning

Tags: xpath

I found the selector "//svg:path" in inkscape source code, but can't find any reference about single colon in XPath. I found for double colon but not useful for this case.

It is in line 117 on [this file](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/extensions/blob/master/dxf12_outlines.py)

Comment: Double colons are used to specify XPath axes.  Single colons are used in XPath (and XML) to specify XML namespace prefixes, abbreviated forms of full XML namespace URIs.  See duplicate links for further details and how to deal with namespaces in XPath.